# store a vector as an (i,j) entry of a matrix in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

This is a simplified version of the project I am doing. I can get around this using other methods. I was just wondering, is it possible to do this in matlab ?
I want to store a 1*2 vector [100,100] to the (1,1) entry of a given matrix a. The following is the code. 
 a=zeros(2,2);
 a(1,1)=[100,100];
Then I get Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch error. 
I could use cell array instead. But there are not so many handy functions (like tril) for cell array compared with matrix. So, I was just wondering, does anyone know how to handle this situation or this is just a trivial case not need to mention at all. Many thanks for your time and attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 3-d matrix instead of 2-d matrix if you already know the length of vector.

```
a = zeros (2,2,2) ;
a(1,1,:) = [100, 100] ;
```

or

```
a =  [];
a (1,1,:) = [100,100];
```

In above example, you have to take care of indexing by yourself and matrix a can be in arbitrary dimensions.

Comment: Yeah. I just realized this. Was intending to delete this post, but saw your answer. Hope no one would down-vote me. Thanks anyway.